# glm or glmm model with unequal variance

Tags: variance, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, glmm

I am applying a GLM model with binomial family:

```
glm(response ~ Treatment, family = binomial, data=dat)
```

The only explaratory variable *treatment* is a categorical variable. The model fit turns out that the residuals clearly do not have equal variances among the treatment levels (heteroscedasticy).
[image]

My question is 1) what I can do in this situation? A gam() is not meaningful for categorical variables. On the other hand, gls() is only applicable for linear model.

2) what if I have an extra random factor in the model (GLMM) and the residuals are still heterogeneous?

```
glmer(response~ Treatment + (1 | groupID), family = binomial, data=dat)
```

Is there any techniques or R packages can solve this?

This question is different from [Regression modelling with unequal variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34325/regression-modelling-with-unequal-variance) which asks similar situations with a linear model.