# Is this a correct regression problem?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have $n$ observations of the following random variables:
$$ Y+X_1,\ Y+X_2,...,\ Y+X_m,$$
where
$${\bf E}X_1=\cdots=
{\bf E}X_m=0.$$
The random variable $Y$ is independent of 
$X_1,...,X_m$.
The random variables $X_1,...,X_m$ are dependent and differently distributed.

Is there a way to estimate the values of $X_1,...,X_m$ in the observations?

Comment: If all the $ X $s have mean 0, presumably you only want to estimate their variance? If so, it sounds like you should look into regression with [heteroscadistic errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors) as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275925/linear-regression-with-changing-variance).

Comment: **This cannot be solved** unless you can describe the nature of the dependency among the $X_i.$  For instance, if you can give their covariance matrix (up to some unknown constant multiple), this problem can be solved with weighted least squares.